Compute $\int \frac{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{e^{-x}+\sin(x)}\ dx$
Let's consider $$\int \frac{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{e^{-x}+\sin(x)}\ dx$$
My attempt is the following.
First, I note that I can rewrite the integrand in the following way (just multiplying numerator and denominator by $e^{x}$):
$$\int \frac{e^x\left(\sin(x)+\cos(x)\right)}{1+e^x\sin(x)}\ dx$$
Now, I use the following substitution: $$t=1+e^x\sin(x) \Longrightarrow dt=e^x\left(\sin(x)+\cos(x)\right)dx$$
Then, $$\int \frac{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{e^{-x}+\sin(x)}\ dx =\int \frac{1}{t}\ dt =\ln|t|+C= \ln|1+e^x\sin(x)|+C$$ where $C\in \mathbb{R}$.
Is it correct? Is the first semplification allowed?
The exercise asks me to compute this primitive in two different ways, any suggestions to another way to solve it, avoiding tecniques that involving non standard methods to calculate the primitive?

Your approach is correct, you are multiplying by $e^x/e^x=1$ in the first step.
Also note that
$$
\int \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{e^{-x}+\sin x} \ dx = \int 
\left( \frac{e^{-x}+\sin x}{e^{-x}+\sin x} + \frac{-e^{-x}+\cos x}{e^{-x}+\sin x} \right) \ dx \\
= \int \left( 1 + \frac{-e^{-x}+\cos x}{e^{-x}+\sin x} \right) \ dx = x+\ln|e^{-x}+\sin x|+C.
$$

Yes, it works very well!
